# How to pass the incoming http requests to RDP machine

Tags: java, maven, proxy, rdp

Sorry if this questions was already asked and answered, i just really have no clue how to ask formulate this question.

So i've got the next issue. I got the access through RDP to the machine in some private network. Also we got some services which is accessible in that private network. That service, which is basically some corporate repository is a place where some dependecies in our project pulled of from. What i trying to do is to configure this project locally, and for that purpose i need the posibility to pull that depenedencies of from that repository on my local machine. This dependecies are pulled by Maven, and as far as i understand basically during the pulling process, it's just a http requests back'n'forward process. In my thoughts, theoreticaly, i could configure somehow some sort of proxy from computer to the RDP machine, and pass all that incoming traffic to the remote machine and answer on the requests there (on the remote machine) and get answers on my local machine.

One more thing worth to mention. I use ZScaller proxy to connect to that machine via RDP. Again, from my thoughts, not that was really an issue, but just in case.

My questions, is that possible, and how can i do it? Any tips for that.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Before doing anything, make sure you won't get fired if you do manage to find a workaround. Some companies would not appreciate you trying to circumvent their isolation.

Comment: Thank you :) In general, i'm not trying to do anything criminal here. My goal is just to moved development to my local machine, as the remote one is quite weak and slow, and all of this requests i mentioned is also pretty isolated. So it's quite safe.

Comment: And also, i can bypass all of this by just uploading all the neccessary dependencies, pack them and send it to my local machine, i did that before. Thing is that that repository is updated quite often, and i don't wanna do that every single time it's got updated. Ofcourse, i can write some bat or python scripts (it run Windows, so the most optimal ways) to automate that, but i want some more generic solution, and not just a rude workarounds (not that my proposed workaround in the topic is better, but at least it looks a bit less awful, and make more sense).